# Android Q dark mode changes color of drawable form white to gray

Tags: android, colors, drawable, android-darkmode

I put an almost white icon (drawable object) on a bright red background (drawn rectangle).
When I switch in dark mode, Android 10 changes the color of the icon into dark gray.
However, I want this icon to remain in its original color in dark mode.
It is the same with the light red drawn rectangle background. Android 10 changes it to a dark red background.

I set the colors in colors and colors (night) and even try to set `Color.WHITE` in my code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
     xMark.setColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(Color.WHITE, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP));
} else {
     xMark.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}
```

How can I get Android 10 to use the color I want even in dark mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling setForceDarkAllowed(false) on the views you want to remain the same when dark mode is enabled.
[See the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setForceDarkAllowed(boolean))